# importing numpy and got Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_intel_thread.1.dylib

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-import

I am using MacBook Pro M1 on Sonoma 14.1 (23B74)
The extensions I am using on VSCode are:
Python v2023.20.0
and
Pylance v2023.11.10

I ran this python code on VSCode

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
x.shape
(4,)
y = np.zeros((2, 3, 4))
y.shape
```

I'm not sure what to call it since it doesn't say Error, but i recieved this message
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_intel_thread.1.dylib.

I also ran it in the terminal and got the same result.

I believe it has to do with the import method but I don't know how to check if I have the environments on my MacBook

I believe the problem has to do with the import line but I am new to coding and don't really know my way around these things (I only hear and see words such as environments , packages, etc but don't understand what they exactly mean or how to locate them on my macbook)

what should I look for to learn about these in a guided way?
Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to include OS version/Python version/how Python was installed (system default? brew?)/how numpy was installed (pip? conda?) ?

Comment: Do you have an M1 or M2 processor?

Comment: @NickODell I edited it. I don't know exactly how any of these were installed 
I once installed anaconda but didn't know how to use it then uninstalled it at some point and when I returned I just used vscode since it was faster to start using 
I don't know if numpy is there now it used to be there when I had anaconda

Comment: @TimRoberts it's MacBook Pro M1 2020
the first macbook model with m1 chip

Comment: It looks like you have installed Python for Intel CPUs, not for ARM CPUs.  The M1 has some Intel emulation, but not for the math primitives.  You can force VSCode to use your system's version of Python instead of its own.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for the explanation I will try to do so